# How to use multiple textures on a cube in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, textures, webgl

This is my source code. It still doesnt work. I want to put 6 different pictures on the 6 sides of a cube, which is animated. Please help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>
<title>WebGL</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">


<script type="text/javascript" src="glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
}
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;


void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var gl;

function initGL(canvas) {
    try {
        gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
        gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
    } catch (e) {
    }
    if (!gl) {
        alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
    }
}


function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while (k) {
        if (k.nodeType == 3) {
            str += k.textContent;
        }
        k = k.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}


var shaderProgram;

function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

    shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
}


var texturen = new Array();
function initTexture(sFilename,texturen)  
{
  var anz = texturen.length;
  texturen[anz] = gl.createTexture();
  texturen[anz].image = new Image();
  texturen[anz].image.onload = function()    
  {
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[anz]);
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
  gl.texImage2D
  (gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texturen[anz].image);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
  }
  texturen[anz].image.src = sFilename;
} 


var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
var mvMatrixStack = [];
var pMatrix = mat4.create();

function mvPushMatrix() {
    var copy = mat4.create();
    mat4.set(mvMatrix, copy);
    mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
}

function mvPopMatrix() {
    if (mvMatrixStack.length == 0) {
        throw "Invalid popMatrix!";
    }
    mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
}


function setMatrixUniforms() {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
}


function degToRad(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function initBuffers() {
    var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
    var vertices = [
        // Front face
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

        // Back face
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

        // Top face
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

       // Bottom face
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

        // Right face
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

        // Left face
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    vertBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    vertBuffer.numItems = 24;


    CoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,CoordBuffer);
    var textureCoords = [
      // Front face
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,

      // Back face
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,

      // Top face
      0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,

   // Bottom face
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,

      // Right face
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,

      // Left face
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    CoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
    CoordBuffer.numItems = 24;

var IndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
    var Indices = [
        0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
        4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
        8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
        12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
        16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
        20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(Indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    IndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
    IndexBuffer.numItems = 36;



}


var xRot = 0;
var yRot = 0;
var zRot = 0;

function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, -5.0]);

    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(xRot), [1, 0, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(yRot), [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, degToRad(zRot), [0, 0, 0]);
    setMatrixUniforms();



gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute,vertBuffer.itemSize, 
  gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// Draw face 0
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[0]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

// Draw face 1
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[1]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 12);

// Draw face 2
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[2]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 24);

// Draw face 3
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[3]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 36);

// Draw face 4
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[4]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 48);

// Draw face 5
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[5]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 60);
}


var lastTime = 0;

function animate() {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if (lastTime != 0) {
        var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

        xRot += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
        yRot += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
        zRot += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
}


function tick() {
    requestAnimFrame(tick);
    drawScene();
    animate();
}


function webGLStart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson05-canvas");
    initGL(canvas);
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();
    initTexture("Logo.png",texturen);
    initTexture("le.png",texturen);
initTexture("Logo.png",texturen);
    initTexture("le.png",texturen);
initTexture("Logo.png",texturen);
    initTexture("le.png",texturen);

gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    tick();
}


</script>


</head>
<body onload="webGLStart();">
<canvas id="lesson05-canvas" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500">    </canvas>    <canvas id="lesson05-canvas" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500">    </canvas>
</body></html>
```

I hope the fact that these are just 2 different pictures doesn't matter.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Black screen? Weird output? Since this is WebGL, it _might_ be useful if you add the browser version you're using. "lesson05-canvas" indicates this is a tutorial from somewhere? Mind stating which? I cannot find any calls to `glGetError`.

Comment: Did the answer to [your first question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11292599/1262542) not satisfy you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you even try to debug this? The code you pasted above does not run and gets JavaScript errors. in Chrome open the JavaScript console (Wrench->Tools->JavaScript Console). In Firefox (Firefox->Web Developer->Web Console)

Things that were wrong

- Lots of globals used but are not actually global.

  Declared `vertBuffer` and `IndexBuffer` and `CoordBuffer` as local variables in 
  `initBuffers` but then used them in `drawScene`.

That made it at least not get JavaScript errors.

- Didn't setup the texture coords.

  The code made a CoordBuffer but never uses it in an attribute. This caused
  GL errors ("attribs not setup correctly" in Chrome)

Fixing this made it stop getting GL errors. At that point I set the background color to green and I saw a spinning black cube which suggested the next problem was textures.

- Not setting the textures up to handle no mips and non-power-of-2 textures.

  If your textures are not power of 2 in each dimension you need to set the texture
  wrap to clamp.

  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

Here's a working version using randomly colored canvases instead of images.

```js
var gl;

function initGL(canvas) {
    try {
        gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
        gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
    } catch (e) {
    }
    if (!gl) {
        alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
    }
}


function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    str = shaderScript.text;

    var shader;
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}


var shaderProgram;

function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    // This is a bad code.
    // If the context is lsot shaderProgram will be null
    // and trying to assign a vertexPositionAttribute to null
    // will throw an exception.
    // better would be 
    // shaderProgram = {};
    // shaderProgram.program = gl.createProgram();
    // shaderProgram.vertexPositionAtrribute = ...
    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

    shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
}


var texturen = new Array();
function initTexture(sFilename,texturen)  
{
  var anz = texturen.length;
  texturen[anz] = gl.createTexture();
  // this is a bad code. on context lost gl.createTexture() will return null and
  // an exception will be thrown when you try to attach .image to null
  // Better would be
  // texturen[anz] = {};
  // texturen[anz].texture = gl.createTexture();
  // texturen[anz].image = new Image();
  texturen[anz].image = new Image();
  texturen[anz].image.onload = function() 
  {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[anz]);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
    //gl.texImage2D  (gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texturen[anz].image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
  }
  //texturen[anz].image.src = sFilename;
  // Since I can't load cross domain I'll use a canvas to make textures
  function rnd() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256); }
  var c = document.createElement("canvas");
  c.width = 64;
  c.height = 64;
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + rnd() + "," + rnd() + "," + rnd() + ")";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + rnd() + "," + rnd() + "," + rnd() + ")";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(32, 32, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fill();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[anz]);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, c);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
} 

var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
var mvMatrixStack = [];
var pMatrix = mat4.create();

function mvPushMatrix() {
    var copy = mat4.create();
    mat4.copy(copy, mvMatrix);
    mvMatrixStack.push(copy);
}

function mvPopMatrix() {
    if (mvMatrixStack.length == 0) {
        throw "Invalid popMatrix!";
    }
    mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
}


function setMatrixUniforms() {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
}

function degToRad(degrees) {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

function initBuffers() {
    vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
    var vertices = [
        // Front face
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

        // Back face
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

        // Top face
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

       // Bottom face
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

        // Right face
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

        // Left face
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    // This is bad code. See the above examples of bad code.
    // vertBuffer will be null on context lost and this code
    // will throw an exception.
    vertBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    vertBuffer.numItems = 24;

    CoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,CoordBuffer);
    var textureCoords = [
      // Front face
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,

      // Back face
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,

      // Top face
      0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,

   // Bottom face
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,

      // Right face
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 0.0,

      // Left face
      0.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 0.0,
      1.0, 1.0,
      0.0, 1.0,
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    CoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
    CoordBuffer.numItems = 24;

    IndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
    var Indices = [
        0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3,    // Front face
        4, 5, 6,      4, 6, 7,    // Back face
        8, 9, 10,     8, 10, 11,  // Top face
        12, 13, 14,   12, 14, 15, // Bottom face
        16, 17, 18,   16, 18, 19, // Right face
        20, 21, 22,   20, 22, 23  // Left face
    ];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(Indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    IndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
    IndexBuffer.numItems = 36;
}


var xRot = 0;
var yRot = 0;
var zRot = 0;

function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0);

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, -5.0]);

    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, degToRad(xRot), [1, 0, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, degToRad(yRot), [0, 1, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, degToRad(zRot), [0, 0, 0]);
    setMatrixUniforms();


    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute,vertBuffer.itemSize, 
       gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, CoordBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute,CoordBuffer.itemSize, 
       gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);

// Draw face 0
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[0]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

// Draw face 1
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[1]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 12);

// Draw face 2
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[2]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 24);

// Draw face 3
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[3]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 36);

// Draw face 4
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[4]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 48);

// Draw face 5
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texturen[5]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 60);
}


var lastTime = 0;

function animate() {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if (lastTime != 0) {
        var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;

        xRot += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
        yRot += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
        zRot += (90 * elapsed) / 1000.0;
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
}


function tick() {
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    drawScene();
    animate();
}


function webGLStart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("lesson05-canvas");
    initGL(canvas);
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();
    initTexture("Logo.png",texturen);
    initTexture("le.png",texturen);
    initTexture("Logo.png",texturen);
    initTexture("le.png",texturen);
    initTexture("Logo.png",texturen);
    initTexture("le.png",texturen);

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    tick();
}


webGLStart();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.2/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
}
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;


void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
</script>

<canvas id="lesson05-canvas" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500">    </canvas>
```

Other problems: There's several places in the code where properties are assigned to WebGL objects. Examples

```
shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = 
    gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
```

...

```
texturen[anz] = gl.createTexture();
texturen[anz].image = new Image();
texturen[anz].image.onload = function()
```

...

```
vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
vertBuffer.itemSize = 3;
```

All of these will have to be refactored if you ever decide to handle context lost events since the `gl.create???` functions will return null and attaching a property to null will cause an exception.

Better to do something more like this

```
shaderProgram = {};
shaderProgram.program = gl.createProgram();
shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = 
    gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
```

...

```
texturen[anz] = {};
texturen[anz].texture = gl.createTexture();
texturen[anz].image = new Image();
texturen[anz].image.onload = function()
```

...

```
vertBuffer = {};
vertBuffer.buffer = gl.createBuffer();
vertBuffer.itemSize = 3;
```

Comment: +1 for "Did you even try to debug this?" :) Debug consoles are your friend!

Comment: Updated your "working version" to [work again](http://jsfiddle.net/YnbTw/22/) (webgl-utils.js has moved)