# How to bind an array of textures to a WebGL shader uniform?

Tags: textures, webgl

I need to handle many objects which share only a few textures. Defining and loading textures one by one manually (as described in [another post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292599/how-to-use-multiple-textures-in-webgl/11300434#11300434)) does not feel right... even more so since there's no `switch (index) {case:...}` statement in WebGL.

So I wanted to pass the texture to use for a vertex as a vertex attribute, and use this number as an index into some "array of textures" in the fragement shader. But the [OpenGL wiki on Samplers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29) (not quite the perfect reference for WebGL, but the one I found) says:

> A variable of sampler can only be defined in one of two ways. It can be defined as a function parameter or as a uniform variable.
>
> uniform sampler2D texture1;

That to me sounds like I can have no array of samplers. I've read a few pages on texture units, but until now, that remains a mystery to me.

In the SO post cited above, Toji hinted at a solution, but wanted a separate question - voila!

Thanks, nobi

PS: I know the other possibility of using a "texture atlas" - if this is more efficient or less complicated - I'd be happy to hear experiences!

Comment: Attribute-tagging is a pretty good idea IMO. I know it goes against one's better instincts, but manual loading and if(aId == 1)c = texture2D(sampler1,p); else if(aID == 2)c = texture2D(sampler2... does at least work. :-/  Texture units are like "scratch pad registers" for textures. Some GL operations, including drawing, need to affiliate 1 texture with 1 texture unit, and it's up to us to dole them out as we see fit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to index sampler arrays with constant values so you can do something like this

```
#define numTextures 4

precision mediump float;
varying float v_textureIndex;
uniform sampler2D u_textures[numTextures];

vec4 getSampleFromArray(sampler2D textures[4], int ndx, vec2 uv) {
    vec4 color = vec4(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < numTextures; ++i) {
      vec4 c = texture2D(u_textures[i], uv);
      if (i == ndx) {
        color += c;
      }
    }
    return color;
}

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = getSampleFromArray(u_textures, int(v_textureIndex), vec2(0.5, 0.5));
}
```

You also need to tell it which texture units to use

```
var textureLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_textures");
// Tell the shader to use texture units 0 to 3
gl.uniform1iv(textureLoc, [0, 1, 2, 3]);
```

The sample above uses a constant texture coord just to keep it simple but of course you can use any texture coordinates.

Here's a sample:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

// Note: createProgramFromScripts will call bindAttribLocation
// based on the index of the attibute names we pass to it.
var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(
    gl, 
    ["vshader", "fshader"], 
    ["a_position", "a_textureIndex"]);
gl.useProgram(program);
var textureLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_textures[0]");
// Tell the shader to use texture units 0 to 3
gl.uniform1iv(textureLoc, [0, 1, 2, 3]);

var positions = [
      1,  1,  
     -1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1,  1,  
     -1, -1,  
      1, -1,  
];
    
var textureIndex = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1,
];

var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(textureIndex), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, false, 0, 0);

var colors = [
    [0, 0, 255, 255],
    [0, 255, 0, 255],
    [255, 0, 0, 255],
    [0, 255, 255, 255],
];

// make 4 textures
colors.forEach(function(color, ndx) {
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + ndx);
    var tex = gl.createTexture();
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
   gl.texImage2D(
      gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0,
      gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(color));
});


gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, positions.length / 2);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script id="vshader" type="whatever">
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    attribute float a_textureIndex;
    varying float v_textureIndex;
    void main() {
      gl_Position = a_position;
      v_textureIndex = a_textureIndex;
    }    
</script>
<script id="fshader" type="whatever">
#define numTextures 4
precision mediump float;
varying float v_textureIndex;
uniform sampler2D u_textures[numTextures];
    
vec4 getSampleFromArray(sampler2D textures[4], int ndx, vec2 uv) {
    vec4 color = vec4(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < numTextures; ++i) {
      vec4 c = texture2D(u_textures[i], uv);
      if (i == ndx) {
        color += c;
      }
    }
    return color;
}
    
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = getSampleFromArray(u_textures, int(v_textureIndex + 0.5), vec2(0.5, 0.5));
}
</script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks promising. I am only wondering why you need to write `if (ndx==0) {...textures[0]...` instead of just writing `textures[ndx]`? And get rid of function `getSampleFromArray` entirely? I'll try this as soon as I'm back from vacation --

Comment: Because WebGL, which is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, doesn't allow indexing a sampler array with anything but a constant-index-expression. See GLSL 1.0.17 Appendix A section 5 [http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf] which means you can index with a constant or a loop index based on constants but nothing else.

Comment: You could do other things like loop through all the textures and multiply by a color. Whether that's faster or slower I don't know. In other words `uniform vec4 u_colors[4]; ... vec4 color = vec4(0,0,0,0); for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { color += texture2D(u_samplers[i], uv) * u_colors[i]; }; gl_FragColor = color; ...` then you can turn off individual textures by setting u_color. In your case I guess you could also do `if (i == (int)(v_textureIndex)) { color = texture2D(...) }`

Comment: works like a charm. It took me a while to figure out that `gl.uniform1iv(textureLoc, [0, 1, 2, 3]);` is setting `u_textures[0]` through `u_textures[3]`, though (at least - I think it's doing that). And there was a limit of 32 textures (and consequently, texture units) being in use at any one time, correct? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, `gl.uniform1iv` is setting `u_textures[0] -> [3]`. The limit for texture units is GPU specific. WebGL requires at least 8. You can call `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)` to find out how many you you get on the user's machine. Vertex shaders have their own limit `gl.getParameter(gl.VERTEX_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)` which can be 0.

Comment: Any easy way to do this using TWGL?  Shouldn't it do it all automatically?  Passing a 1-element array as uniform doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Oh, actually when the array size is 1, it only works by setting the uniform to the texture, not a 1-element array containing the texture, buf for other values it works just fine :)

Comment: [It works just fine with a one element array](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/74ax0kyc/). you have some other bug if it's not working for you.